# Leaking Shower Pan

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak

I took a shower today then later went down to my basement and saw a puddle of water - there's a leak that seems to be coming not from the drain but from the edge of the shower pan - I suspect the drain's fitting came loose or cracked or something similar. My thinking is I can either try to replace the fittings from the basement, coat the inside with a putty, or hire a plumber.

*From the basement side, the leak is in line with the radiator but over by the shower -- it is certainly a shower leak (only leaks when the shower has been on for ~3+ minutes).

I looked at this post, [Repair shower drain leak](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/151018/repair-shower-drain-leak), that describes how the flange can be replaced, but my intuition is the water is flowing around the strainer body onto the shower pan then traveling to a nail pop or something similar -- if. that's the case, my thinking would be to remove the strainer body, add plumber's putty and a gasket and replace the strainer body -- that'd [hopefully] seal around the edge of the drain head.

I'm just spit-balling here though, so any insight or advice would be much appreciated

[image: leak near end of shower pan]
[image: basement relative to shower drain]
[image: shower drain]
[image: bathroom]
[image: basement view of flange]

Comment: Personally, my suspect would be a poor seal on the composite surround.  OP doesn't really indicate where the leak is above the floor (orientation of shower w.r.t. joists).

Answer (score -1):

From the black stains on the wood, that drain has been leaking for some time.
Water should not be getting between the drain flange and the shower base.

Loosen the drain. Clean the base and the flange well and add plenty of new plumbers putty. Tighten things up, but don't over tighten.

That should cure your problem.

Comment: The OP's pics appear to indicate that it's *not* the drain that's leaking.

Comment: The pan is one piece.  The only opening is  for the drain.  The water is seeping from a small gap and the  running across the bottom of the pan until it drips off.  Not unlike a leak in a roof showing itself far from the origin.

Comment: Except that in a roof leak, the water runs downhill and shows up somewhere else. You're proposing that the water is running *uphill* from the drain (since the drain is presumably the lowest point in the shower pan) to appear somewhere else  Seems unlikely ...

Comment: You have assumed that the underside of the pan is flat and runs parallel to the floor. However many pans are reinforced around the drain and have reinforcing ribs. I have seen this type of leak before. Water seeping from the drain and not dripping until it gets to the edge of the pan. You may think it can't happen, but I have seen it . The sides lap over a flange on the pan. A leak there means water would have to climb over the flange and then drip down, You believe that can happen.